# How to determine negative trigrams

Tags: r, text-mining

I am trying to search through a load of medical reports. I want to determine the type of language used to say an absence of a finding. Eg "There is no blabla" or "Neither blabla nor bleble is seen here". There are many variations.

My original idea was to divide the text into trigrams and then perform sentiment analysis on the trigrams, and then have a look at the negative trigrams and manually select the ones that denote an absence of something. Then I wanted to design some regular expressions around these absence trigrams.

I get the feeling however that I am not really looking for a sentiment analysis but more of a negation search. I could, I suppose just look for all sentences with 'not' or 'neither' or 'nor or 'no' but I'm sure I'll fall into some kind of linguistic trap.

Does anyone have a comment on my sentiment approach and if this is correct can I have some guidance about sentiment analysis on trigrams (or bigrams I suppose) as all the R tutorials I have found demonstrate unigram sentiment analysis.